# Manipulate arraylist elements inside for loop (jsp/jstl) without using scriptlets

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl

I have to manipulate an arraylist after checking conditions like if value already exists, do nothing. If id matches with entered id, update name etc. I know how to achieve these with scriptlet tag but I am not allowed to use them. I have to use tag libraries.

I have to achieve this but with jstl

```
 for(grade g:gradeArray)
{
 if(g.getLevelId==levelId)
{
g.setLevelName(levelName);
 }}
```

With jstl i only know how to iterate over an arraylist and to print those values

Comment: JSTL is part of the View from the Model-View-Controller pattern, so it is meant to display the data, not to manipulate them.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. But is there any way to manipulate them because we are said to use jstl and jsp only not even servlets.